B&W Movie or tv show about a painter who builds some device to paint for him
I saw a movie or possibly a tv episode of a series when I was very young (about 50 yrs ago).  Amazingly I can't find answer with Google.   I remember it as black and white but whether it was filmed in black & white or I saw it on a black & white tv set I don't know.  
All I've got to work with from my memory is a painter builds some devices to do his painting for him.   I don't recall if they were controlled mechanically or through sorcery of some sort.  They were long arms that towered over the artist by twice his height with brushes attached to the ends.   At the end of the movie/show, these creations turned on him, killing him.
Any ideas? 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

To me this sounds like the second segment of What a Way to Go! (1964) in which the often widowed Louise May Foster (Shirley MacLaine) explains to psychiatrist Dr. Victor Stephenson (Robert Cummings) the fate of her second husband Larry flint (Paul Newman, an artist with painting machines.
Wikipedia
IMDb
